# SQLite error in android Xamarin Project

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, xamarin

I get this exception when hitting this line of code in my project. Any ideas?

line of code:

```
var JsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginModel>(ResultData);
```

exception:

```
{System.MissingMethodException: Method 'SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrementAttribute..ctor' not found.
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoCustomAttrs:IsDefinedInternal (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,System.Type)
at System.MonoCustomA...
```

oddly it works fine if I run the project in Visual Studio for Mac 2017, but when I run it on VS 2017 on Win 10 I get this exception. Exact same code, no changes. So it must be an environmental thing, but I have no clue what.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009407/rest-exception-unable-to-find-a-constructor-to-use-for-type-myclass-a-class) answer.
This is linker stripping away your methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rest exception: Unable to find a constructor to use for type "myclass". A class should either have a default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009407/rest-exception-unable-to-find-a-constructor-to-use-for-type-myclass-a-class)

Comment: What's the version of your Mono? Both in Mac and Win 10.